# SWOT Analysis box design

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to create bellow box

[image]

i have used below HTM code

```css
.noMargin {
 margin: 0px;
}
 .bordertp {
 border-top: 1px solid grey;
}
 .borderbtm {
 border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
 .borderright{
 border-right: 1px solid grey;
}
 .borderleft{
 border-left: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row noMargin bordertp borderleft borderright">
<div class="col one borderright"> one </div>
<div class="col two"> two </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row noMargin borderbtm borderleft borderright">
<div class="col three"> three </div>
<div class="col four"> four </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but not able to figure out how to add the cross in the middle and 4 colored box and the numbers. any easy way to archive this. if someone already done it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add more Css and HTML to do it a bit easier then it is.You can make use of [display: flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/); to get those divs behave like they should.

In my code you can see that i wrapped the number and the character in a new div to align them properly alongside the other ones.

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row noMargin">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="number">
                    5
                  </div>
                  <div class="text">
                    S
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="number">
                    1
                  </div>
                  <div class="text">
                    W
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row noMargin">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="number">
                    3
                  </div>
                  <div class="text">
                    O
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="number">
                    0
                  </div>
                  <div class="text">
                    T
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I used the '+' selector and the :first-child selector of css to target the right divs without giving them specific classes. Those operators are explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)

```
.noMargin {
  margin: 0px;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
/* Select second row (following on other row) */
.row + .row {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
} 
.row .col {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row .col + .col {
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}

.row .col + .col .number {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.row .col:first-child .text {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

You still need to add the colors.

Comment: if i add the outside box then the cross need to have some gap between the borders like in the image i uploaded

Comment: Add everything in another DIV and give that Div padding: 10px (or more) and border: 1px solid grey;